# REACT application does not work after the page is refreshed with F5

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. In the App.js file, I have this simple component.

```
const p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

p.innerHTML = "Created with Javascript";


function App() {
  return <p>Created with JSX</p>;
}
export default App;
```

As I expected, this is the result in my Browser.

> Created with Javascript

But when I refresh the page with F5, the page is blank and I get this bug in the console.

```
>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')  
    >at Module../src/App.js (bundle.js:22:13)  
    >at Module.options.factory (bundle.js:41603:31)  
    >at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:41075:33)  
    >at fn (bundle.js:41274:21)  
    >at Module../src/index.js (bundle.js:84:62)  
    >at Module.options.factory (bundle.js:41603:31)  
    >at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:41075:33)  
    >at bundle.js:42178:37  
    >at bundle.js:42180:12
```

Why is this happening? I expected the same result after refreshing the page with F5.

Comment: You're not supposed to use document methods, React was made for that...
You should check out the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: This is happening because the `<p>` element doesn't yet exist when this code: `const p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];` runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, because `p` is `undefined`.
As long as nothing rendered on the page `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];` will not be able to select anything.

You have to wait until rendering finishes and then select the html element.

You could use a `useLayoutEffect` for that, or you could rewrite your code to anticipate the usage of `react` with a `ref` from `useRef`. But for that we will need to know your use case.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I understand - "p" is not defined. But the funny thing is though that when the page renders for the first time, it works. But once I refresh the page, it does not. Any, as Rukka suggested, I will have to read the docs. That is the best way I should go I think.